# How to get count in SQL if the column value is something specific

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to show the count in the SQL query, but I have a problem with it. I want to search for count only if there is something specific in the value column. Here is an example of my query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(IF status='F') FROM relation WHERE from='7'
```

So, here I want to get the amount of "relation" from the column "status" from the table, when the status value is F.

With the above code, I get an error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`status`='F') FROM `relation` WHERE `from`='7' LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

Comment: Please include the table you want to get the data from.

Comment: why don't you put tht status check in where clause?

Comment: Please show some sample data and the expected result

Comment: Lots of answers already, but I'd just like to recommend avoiding use SQL keywords as column names. You have a column called "from". It would be better to change it to something like "value_from"

Answer (score 2):

I think two common ways are:

```
SELECT 
 COUNT(CASE WHEN status='F' THEN 1 END) 
FROM relation
WHERE from='7'
```

and

```
SELECT
 SUM(CASE WHEN status='F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM relation
WHERE from='7'
```

The first one uses `count` but since it only counts non-null values, it only counts the ones you want. The second uses `sum`, but since we sum 1 if your condition is true and 0 if your condition is false it's equivalent to counting where the condition is true.

Although in your case since you're not doing a `group by` you could just use

```
SELECT
 COUNT(*)
FROM relation
WHERE from='7' AND status='F'
```

Comment: In MYSQL, the second can be written without case when, just SUM(status='F')

Answer (score 1):

You can count this way to get **only counts** where the value of `status` is **F**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM relation WHERE from='7' AND status='F';
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer summing a boolean expression:

```sql
SELECT SUM(status = 'F') AS cnt
FROM relation
WHERE `from` = '7';
```

Note that `FROM` is a reserved MySQL keyword.  If you really did name a column `FROM`, then you will have to forever escape it in backticks.  You should avoid naming your database objects using reserved keywords.

Comment: I know, this table also has its own column called "from". That's why I used a character like this in between: `from`

Comment: This character: `